# Apple's Server-Side Swift Framework

Tags: ios, swift, macos, server-side

Does Apple have its own Swift (or, at least, Objective-C) `server-side framework` with similar capabilities like [Vapor](https://vapor.codes) or [Kitura](https://www.kitura.io) have?

I'm not interested in using third-party frameworks or Cocoapods.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked https://swift.org/server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vapor and Kitura are both build on Apples [Swift-NIO](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio).
So you could technicaly go with that as well but you would have to build alot of functionality by yourself that frameworks like vapor and kitura bring, to make you life easier.